# PLM QM Audit: disable signature button / signature requirement; make an audit object(s) a mandatory field

Tags: abap, audit, sap-erp

There are a number of changes in PLM QM Audit module with which I am struggling at the moment.

First requirement: disable (deactivate) **Signature** button in the *Result tab* of the audit object and therefore also the pre-requirement to sign (click this button) in order to change the audit status to **Complete**:

[image: Result tab]

Second requirement is: make **audit objects** by audit creation to be **mandatory** to enter. At the moment the default behavior of the system is just to give a warning if nothing was entered for an audit object and further saving and processing of the audit is possible:

[image: Audit objects]

Maybe someone already has faced with these issues before.

Customizing settings / possibilities and some coding of the module were checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

###### First requirement

Not possible to implement in a delivered application (except of course the modification of the application code itself, but it is already far from standard functionality and is better to be avoided for maintainability / future compatibility reasons).

What is possible, however, is to *sign and close the audit in one step* (set the status to **Completed**)  by clicking on the **Signature** button. [SAP Note 2694780](https://me.sap.com/notes/2694780)

To activate this behavior it is necessary to set the user parameter  `PLM_AUDIT_SIGN_COMPL` to a non-empty value (i.e. to `X`).

###### Second requirement

As was discovered this is a standard behavior now and it was changed in the past: [SAP Note 1158350](https://me.sap.com/notes/1158350)

*Saving* of the audit is *allowed* with empty audit objects, on this stage only warning messages are issued, and the **error message** is only issued when an **audit is released**.

The relevant code:

Class: CL_PLM_AUDIT_ASSIGNMENT
Method: CHECK_AUDITED_OBJECT
Parameter: IV_MSGTY default value '**W**'

```
...
  " Check is only possible if audit type is known
  CHECK NOT me->audit_attributes-audit_type IS INITIAL.

  " Set message type (used only for checking whether object is provided;
  " non-existing object always results in error message)
  lv_msgty = iv_msgty.
  IF lv_msgty IS INITIAL.
    lv_msgty = cgplc_con_msg_warning.
  ENDIF.
...

  " check if all object values are given (obligatory field)
  " no object defined yet
  IF ls_plmm_audit_obj-object_value IS INITIAL.
    MESSAGE e025(plm_audit)
      WITH lr_audited_object->m_auditobject_text
      INTO lv_msgtext.
    CALL METHOD cl_cgpl_application_log=>message_add
      EXPORTING
        im_msgty = lv_msgty
        im_msgid = sy-msgid
        im_msgno = sy-msgno
        im_msgv1 = sy-msgv1.
    lv_result = 'E'.
    MOVE lv_result TO cv_result.
...
```

Type group CGPLC Active (CGPL Planung: Definition of Constants):

```
...
  cgplc_con_msg_warning  TYPE c VALUE 'W',
...
```

There is also a BAdI `PLM_AUDIT_OBJECT` (Standard Implementation of Audit Object: Cust. Value Table) available, where it is possible to change the process.